# Phase Lines and classifying steady states.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Plot the phase lines and classify the fixed points of the following:

(please excuse the shoddily drawn phase lines)

$dy/dt=y^2$ : $- \infty$  --->---0---->----   $ \infty$, Which would make this point a node.

$dy/dt=y(y-2)$ : $- \infty$ ---<---0--->--- $ \infty$, making this point a source.

$dy/dt= ye^{(y-1)}$ : $ - \infty$ ----<----0---->--- $\infty$, again making this point a source.

$dy/dt= sin(y) \dot cos(y)$ : $- \infty$ ----<----0---->---- $\infty$, again, another source.

Are these conclusions correct? It seemed too easy to me, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The second one cannot be correct because there are clearly two critical points. The fourth one cannot be correct because you have periodic critical points.

Comment: @Moo Quite right, thank you. I certainly forgot about the second critical on the second and when I graphed the fourth one, i oriented my axes wrong. Time for me to go to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm incorrect in this assumption, but I assume by fixed points you mean steady states/equilibrium points. If so, you should identify them for each function and see what happens around each one to get your phase lines.

For $dy/dt=y^2$, you have a double root at $y = 0$.

Now look at both sides of $y = 0$ i.e. $ y < 0 $ and $y > 0$, you find that it is positive on both sides. Hence, your phase diagram is correct.

$−∞ --->---0---->---- ∞$

However, you should specify, what point you are referring to when you say it is a node. You should say $y = 0$ is a node.

For $dy/dt=y(y−2)$, you have roots at $y = 0$ and $y = 2$.

At $y = 0$, if you look at $y < 0$, you see that $dy/dt$ is positive. At $0< y < 2$, you see that $dy/dt$ is negative. Therefore, $y = 0$ is a sink. For $y = 2$, at $0< y < 2$, you see that $dy/dt$ is negative. At $y > 2$, you see that $dy/dt$ is positive. Therefore, $y = 2$ is a sink. So your phase diagram should look like :

$−∞ --->---0--<--2-->---∞$

For $dy/dt=ye^{(y−1)}$, since e to any power will never result in 0, we need only look at the other term. Therefore, you have one root at $y = 0$.

If you consider what happens at $y < 0$, $dy/dt$ is negative and at $y > 0$, $dy/dt$ is positive. This means $y = 0$ is a source. Your phase diagram should look like:

$−∞ ---<----0---->--- ∞$

For $dy/dt=sin(y)cos(y)$, it gets a bit tricky. $sin(y) = 0$ at $y = n\pi$ for n and $cos(y) = 0$ at $y = n\pi/2$ for all odd n.

Here, you have to decide where you want to stop, but since you can see the repetition of the pattern, I recommend saying you have roots as described above, but only plot a few on your phase diagram, i.e. $y = \{-2\pi, -3\pi/2, -\pi, -\pi/2, 0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2, 2\pi\}$ You will find that periodically, when moving from a $y = n\pi$ root to a $y = n\pi/2$ root, you find that $dy/dt$ is positive and when moving from a $y = n\pi/2$ root to a $y = n\pi$ root, $dy/dt$ is negative. Therefore, your phase line will look something like:

$−∞ --(-2\pi)->-(-3\pi/2)-<-(-\pi)->-(-\pi/2)-<-0->-\pi/2-<-\pi->-3\pi/2-<-2\pi-->-- ∞$

So all roots of the form $y = n\pi,$ $n \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$ are sources and all roots of the form $y = n\pi,$ $n \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$, n is odd are sinks.

Comment: Thank you, and yes fixed points are my text's terminology for this. And thank you, I overlooked a critical value in the second one and actually oriented my axes incorrectly for the fourth. Great answer, thank you!!